# Flex and multi-monitor support

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, multiple-monitors

I have a situation where my Flex application will need to detect multi-monitors and their respective resolutions and positions.

So far, I have tried using JavaScript code to determine the width/height ratio of the screen; however, it lacks precise details about

1. the resolution of each of the monitors;
2. their respective locations;
3. and the width/height ratio does not guarantee anything since many monitors could be wide-screen monitors

I have been stuck with this situation for almost a week now and I still couldn't figure out a possible workaround. All workarounds are welcome, only that I do not intend to install applications that would then communicate with my Flex application (that is, [AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) desktop for Flex web-based applications).

### 2011-08-23

I finally solved this problem using a Java applet and JavaScript. With that, I can use FAbridge for the values obtained in the JavaScript.

Comment: Flex sits in the browser, so you can't do it from there. You'll have to use javascript (if at all possible).I tried to re-tag your question, but I do not seem to have sufficient privileges.

Comment: @RIAstar thanks, i tagged javascript. Do you have a better workaround with javascript?  THANKS!

Comment: As far as I know JS can only detect the resolution of the screen the browser is in.

Answer (score 0):

I tried look into the Flash Player 11 Pre-release documentation for Molehill/GPU access information. You might want to look in your own version of the docs and experiment with

```
flash.system.Capabilities -

screenResolutionX : Number [static] [read-only] 
Specifies the maximum horizontal resolution of the screen.

screenResolutionY : Number [static] [read-only] 
Specifies the maximum vertical resolution of the screen.
```

If it works out, you try to infer how many monitors they have by doing the math. In my case my screenResolutionX = 3360px which would mean I have two 1680 x 1050 displays. Inferring displays sizes for sets with mixed sizes of monitors will be a b!tch to guess but it can be done. You'll just have to figure out the permutations of the combinations. Nothing I read says anything about their locations, so you might want to work with your app to be top left corner (0,0) based rather than relative to the middle.

Very interesting dilemma you have, forces us to think out of the box...the Flash Player stage box that is.

Comment: Thanks,  but that only limited to FP11-pre release right?  I tried that in fp9/fp10 before i tried javascript.  It didnt work.  It only reported the screen resolution of the current monitor that the browser sat in.

Comment: I have to qualify when I said 'in my case', I meant my hardware. Softwarewise, I haven't tested the code. flash.system.Capabilities has been around for a while, so whatever behaviors happen in fp9/fp10 will likely be the same in fp11.

Comment: Well like i said, in my case, Capabilities didn't work out like how you expected even thought we both know its been here for a while.   Good try tho.